# Powershell multiple .sql files to custom .txt files

Tags: powershell, txt

I am totally new to Powershell. I feel as though I have exhausted looking on the internet, but I also know that this answer ***should*** be easy.

I want a loop to:

1. Run 50 SQL files
2. Save them as a custom named txt file

For example, if SQL Files are:

1. E:\SQLscripts\apples.sql
2. E:\SQLscripts\bananas.sql
3. E:\SQLscripts\clementines.sql
4. E:\SQLscripts\oranges.sql
5. E:\SQLscripts\watermelons.sql
6. etc.

I want to have:

1. E:\OutputTXT\apples.txt
2. E:\OutputTXT\bananas.txt
3. E:\OutputTXT\clementines.txt
4. E:\OutputTXT\oranges.txt
5. E:\OutputTXT\watermelons.txt
6. etc.

Rather than posting 10 different chunks of code, I have tried the following

- Export-CSV -NoTypeInformation
- Export-CSV -NoTypeInformation -Force
- Export-CSV -NoTypeInformation -Force -
- Out-File $outdir.$filename.basename.txt
- Out-File %filename.basename.txt%
- Out-File ($filename.Basename + ".txt")
- Path ($outdir + $filename.Name + ".csv")

```
    $sqlserver = 'local'
    $sqldb = 'dbname'
    $sqluser = 'user'
    $sqlpw = 'pw'
    $sourcedir = 'E:\SQLscripts'
    $outdir = 'E:\OutputTXT'


    foreach ($filename in get-childitem -Path $sourcedir -Filter "*.sql") {
    invoke-sqlcmd –ServerInstance $sqlserver -Database $sqldb -Username $sqluser -Password           
    $sqlpw -InputFile $filename.fullname |
    (missing piece here)
    }
```

Comment: What is your question? How to write output from a command to a file?

Comment: I want to:1. run all sql files 2. save the query results to a txt file with the same corresponding basename of the sql file. For example, if have sqlfile1.sql I want it to output to sqlfile1.txt. Since I have 30 sql files, though, I want to do this in a looped and automated way. Hope that helps clarify!